# Images are not displaying with <li> tag in map function for array object in Reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I don't understand why this is not working. I have tried to do some research about the relative problem but I have no luck to solve.

I have a array-like objects like this and the component to render this array-like objects:

```
const socialMediaResourceItems = 
[
    {
        id: 1,
        image: '../images/1.jpg',
        alt: 'hi',
        url: '#'
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        image: "../images/2.jpg",
        alt: 'hi',
        url: '#'
    }
]

const SocialMediaResources = () => {
    const socialMediaList = socialMediaResourceItems.map((socialMediaResourceItem) => {
    return (
            <li key={socialMediaResourceItem.id}>
                {/* <img src={require(`${socialMediaResourceItem.image}`)} alt={socialMediaResourceItem.alt} />   */}
                <img src={socialMediaResourceItem.image} alt={socialMediaResourceItem.alt} />  
            </li>
    )
})

return (
    <div className="link-groups">
        {socialMediaList}
    </div>
  )
};

export default SocialMediaResources
```

I have tired just to import them with relative path and do src={../images/1.jpg}, and it works, but when I put them for the property of object, then it shows a tiny weird picture like this
[image]

I also tried to use require() for other component, and it works as well.

What am I missing here? I don't think I need webpack for this tho.
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

Since you have fixed your image path like '../images/' so you also can use js string literals like `src=`../images/${socialMediaResourceItem.image} as I have updated your code below:

```
const socialMediaResourceItems = 
[
    {
        id: 1,
        image: '1.jpg',
        alt: 'hi',
        url: '#'
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        image: '2.jpg',
        alt: 'hi',
        url: '#'
    }
]

const SocialMediaResources = () => {
    const socialMediaList = socialMediaResourceItems.map((socialMediaResourceItem) => (
            <li key={socialMediaResourceItem.id}>
                {/* <img src={require(`${socialMediaResourceItem.image}`)} alt={socialMediaResourceItem.alt} />   */}
                <img src=`../images/${socialMediaResourceItem.image}` alt={socialMediaResourceItem.alt} />  
            </li>
    )
)

return (
    <div className="link-groups">
        {socialMediaList}
    </div>
  )
};

export default SocialMediaResources
```

Comment: Thanks for replying. In your response, it should be src={`../images/${socialMediaResourceItem.image}`} , but unfortunately, it's not working. Still can't see the image.

Answer (score 0):

Since your images are not in the public folder you need to import each of the images.Consider the following code

```
import image1 from '../images/1.jpg'
import image2 from '../images/2.jpg'
const socialMediaResourceItems = 
[
    {
        id: 1,
        image: image1,
        alt: 'hi',
        url: '#'
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        image: image2
        alt: 'hi',
        url: '#'
    }
]

const SocialMediaResources = () => {
    const socialMediaList = socialMediaResourceItems.map((socialMediaResourceItem) => {
    return (
            <li key={socialMediaResourceItem.id}>
                {/* <img src={require(`${socialMediaResourceItem.image}`)} alt={socialMediaResourceItem.alt} />   */}
                <img src={socialMediaResourceItem.image} alt={socialMediaResourceItem.alt} />  
            </li>
    )
})

return (
    <div className="link-groups">
        {socialMediaList}
    </div>
  )
};

export default SocialMediaResources
```

if you want to avoid importing the image,it is better to put the images in the public folder of the react app and you can load the image directly as

```
    const path = '1.jpg'
     .....
    render() {
         return(<img src={path} className="mr-10" alt="Loading" />)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution I found it:

```
const socialMediaResourceItems = 
[
    {
         id: 1,
         image: '1.jpg',
         alt: 'hi',
         url: '#'
    },
    {
         id: 2,
         image: "2.jpg",
         alt: 'hi',
         url: '#'
    }
]

const SocialMediaResources = () => {
const socialMediaList = socialMediaResourceItems.map((socialMediaResourceItem) => {
return (
        <li key={socialMediaResourceItem.id}>
            <img 
                src={require(`../images/${socialMediaResourceItem.image}`)} 
                alt={socialMediaResourceItem.alt}
            />
        </li>
       )
})

return (
    <div className="link-groups">
        {socialMediaList}
    </div>
  )
};

export default SocialMediaResources
```